# Usage of while and continuous: "Tom watches/is watching TV while he eats/is eating."

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, present-continuous

> A) Tom watches TV while he eats.
>
> B) Tom watches TV while he is eating.
>
> C) Tom is watching TV while he eats.
>
> D) Tom is watching TV while he is eating.

I was wondering which one is natural and which one is not and want to know the difference between them.

Comment: I think both A and B are indicating that another person is saying tom always eats while watching tv (though B. sounds more natural). C is kind of like a present tense or still occurring since **is** is added and s is added to eat**s** while D is the same but it's like another person is talking to someone where they're mentioning tom. Overall B is a better version of A when talking about the 'past' and D for "now."

Comment: (A) and (B) _could_ both be a statement of Tom's usual habit at mealtimes, or they could simply state what he does on this particular occasion. None of them strikes me as being less 'natural' than the others.